# Растянуть grid внутри listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Переопределил шаблон листбокса, чтобы создать, что-то на подобии истории смс, но грид не растягивается по всей области listboxitem. Не подскажите как можно решить эту проблему. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbMsg" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionMsg}">

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="girdLb" Background="AliceBlue">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="100" CornerRadius="50,50,50,0" Visibility="{Binding visible_client}" Background="Yellow" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding client}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="100" CornerRadius="50,50,0,50" Visibility="{Binding visible_tech}" Background="Yellow" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding tech_support}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: убрать конкретные размеры для столбцов, например

Comment: все зависит от того, какое отображение вы хотите получить

Answer (score 0):

Можно привязать ширину Grid к ширине ListBox

```
<Grid x:Name="girdLb" Background="AliceBlue" Width="{Binding ElementName=lbMsg, Path=ActualWidth}">
```

Comment: Это решение плохо тем, что не будет работать если добавить Margin/Padding